# Finding The Zero vector

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces

We can find the zero vector of a set V that we want to prove is a vector space by finding the additive indentity. But when we find it, it doesn’t mean that the set V of vectors that we have is necessarily a vector space? How do we check if the set is not empty( contains the zero vector)?

Comment: Usually it is clear what vector is zero and there is no reason to "search."  I cannot think of any examples where you would need to search, can you?

Comment: Yes if the defined operations are like this:

Comment: Okay i’ll Add a photo

Comment: I don’t have enough reputations, if the operations are not standard

Comment: Like (a,b)+(b,c)=(a+b+1,b+c+1)

Comment: Take any vector $\vec{v} \in V$ and multiply by the scalar 0, then you have the zero vector $\vec{0} = 0\vec{v}$.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking about this method, it will always verify the answer! But José says that if we find the additive identity it’s sufficient

Comment: I don't think anyone knows what you mean by "it's sufficient."  You might be drawing unintended conclusions from Jose's answer (his answer says that if a set has at least one element, then the set is non-empty).  I doubt this fact really helps you. My guess is that you have a set of potential "vectors" with unusual operations for addition and scalar multiplication, and you must verify whether or not it is a vector space. So the addition operation might satisfy the commutative property and might have an additive identity, but some other property (like the distributed law) does not hold.

Comment: I see, but when I say an non-empty set, I mean that the set contains the zero vector!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have answered your own question: if you find an additive identity, then the set $V$ is automatically non-empty.

Comment: Oh really! I don’t know why I’ve read somewhere that even if we found the Zero vector, it doesn’t necessarily mean that It is in the set V.

Comment: In that case don’t you think that if we define operations and search for the additive indentity we’ll always find it? But sometimes sets are empty? Can you give an example where we cannot find the additive indentity?

Comment: @DanielKamand There is no additive identity in $(\mathbb{N},+)$.

Comment: Depending whether we consider 0 as a natural number or not.